# Postfix with many ips

Tags: centos, postfix-mta, mail-server

Hello I am installing a Postfix in CentOs 6.2, the thing is that I have a block of a few IPs, lets say 5 ips where I want the email will be deliver from, So the first petition to send an email the server will use the first ip, later the second and so on, How can I setup that?.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution,if you can implement this ideas to your postfix then you can arrange the IPs like your wish,

1)Give message ID to your each mails in a increasing manner
2)In transport you can give a mails tunneled as the message ID
NOTE:If you are using 5 IPs then you can calculate ID%5=1 then 1st IP  ID%5=2 then 2nd IP. You can do it with the help of regular expression([link](http://www.postfix.org/transport.5.html)).